# Read files from remote repository using nixOs

Tags: nix, nixos

I am building a project using the nixOs package system.
I have a remote git repo containing different config files.
I want to access those files using nix, with out editing the remote repo.

The project would access the remote repo with a specific commit hash.
Could anyone help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short derivation that reads a file from a remote git repo that contains no Nix configuration:

```
with (import <nixpkgs> { });
let
  repo = fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "nix-community";
    repo = "awesome-nix";
    rev = "c4adba38dc2ec33aa0f692cc5fcb9677b123087c";
    sha256 = "cF9sh3vrDwTh64ZkgyEuJKmmA4UhbnXw8x4cnBMeGHk=";
  };
in stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "count-repo-lines";
  src = repo;
  buildPhase = ''
    mkdir $out
    wc -l ./README.md > linecount
  '';
  installPhase = ''
    cp linecount $out/linecount
  '';
  system = builtins.currentSystem;
}
```

If it were saved to a file named `count-remote-lines.nix`, then the `nix-build` command would put the output into a local folder named `result`:

```
$ nix-build ./count-remote-lines.nix
...various log messages...

$ cat ./result/linecount 
154 ./README.md
```

Alternatively, to better troubleshoot the derivation's build process by stepping through it in an interactive shell, try:

```
$ nix-shell ./count-repo-lines.nix --pure

$ unpackPhase
unpacking source archive /nix/store/xaff1yqipbpazhp9jz22rjp7izbglzr5-source
source root is source

$ cd source
$ ls
CONTRIBUTING.md  LICENSE  README.md
```

The remaining build commands are documented in `man nix-shell`, under Examples. [Also in wiki pages such as this one.](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Packaging/Tutorial)

Comment: Thank you it's working !